# RDS: Client not connecting to session host, direct connect works fine

Tags: rds

## Environment

- Fully patched Windows 7 Client
- Fully patched Server 2012R2 Environment
- RDS-Deployment with two HA connection brokers, three session hosts, one WA host
- externally available RDS gateway, connection is made from within the company network though
- Client and RDS environment on different networks, connected via IPSec VPN
- I've got this problem on four clients now, more than a 150 work fine

## Problem

[image: connectionerror]

- When I try to connect to the RDS environment, it fails. Roughly translated from german, the UI message says `For your computer, no connection to the remotecomputer could be made. Please reconnect. Ask your administrator if the problem persists.`

## What I've seen and tried

### Clientside

[image: eventlog entry]

- In the clients eventlog, the only event I can see is ID 1041: `The remote app "DNS name of my broker setup" is getting started in "DNS name of my broker setup", but no saved credentials are used for one time logon. (Reason: RemoteApp- and Remotedesktop connection do not exist).`
- connecting directly to a session host via `mstsc.exe /admin` works fine
- **using wireshark while connecting, I can not see a single TCP packet being transmitted to the connection broker or gateway**. When connecting directly, I do.
- Deleting my Root-CA from the certstore and re-importing did not help
- Tracing it via procexp shows nothing unusual
- completely uninstalled antivirus solution "Bitdefender"
- used a fresh RDP connection file that works fine on any other client
- used an unsigned RDP connection

### Serverside

- Failover to the second connection broker node did not change the situation
- I can not find any entries in the brokers event logs

What could cause a client to fail connecting before even transmitting a single packet to the connection broker, while connecting fine directly?

Thanks for **any** hint. I'm out of ideas what to test, but don't want to simply resetup the machine because it is not a single case anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the machine from the domain, rejoining and various other tests, I just solved it by removing the "workspacesid"-line from the RDP file. I can now connect just fine

Unfortunately, I can't find any detailed documentation from microsoft on this, but I'll still mark as solved.